# Vue.js - problem running existing project

Tags: javascript, python, node.js, vue.js, npm

I want to launch a ready-made UI project coded with vue.js. But when I type the npm install command, I get the following error. Python is already installed. The environment variable is also set, I can access the compiler when I write python via CMD. How can I solve this?

```
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path C:\Users\ismai\Desktop\smartupwebui\smartupui\app-src\node_modules\fibers
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /d /s /c node build.js || nodejs build.js
npm ERR! gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
npm ERR! gyp info using node-gyp@3.8.0
npm ERR! gyp info using node@18.12.1 | win32 | x64
npm ERR! gyp ERR! configure error 
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack Error: Can't find Python executable "python", you can set the PYTHON env variable.
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at PythonFinder.failNoPython (C:\Users\ismai\Desktop\smartupwebui\smartupui\app-src\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\configure.js:484:19)       
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at PythonFinder.<anonymous> (C:\Users\ismai\Desktop\smartupwebui\smartupui\app-src\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\configure.js:509:16)        
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at callback (C:\Users\ismai\Desktop\smartupwebui\smartupui\app-src\node_modules\graceful-fs\polyfills.js:295:20)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (node:fs:207:21)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.22621
npm ERR! gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\ismai\\Desktop\\smartupwebui\\smartupui\\app-src\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild" "--release"
npm ERR! gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\ismai\Desktop\smartupwebui\smartupui\app-src\node_modules\fibers
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node -v v18.12.1
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.8.0
npm ERR! gyp ERR! not ok
npm ERR! node-gyp exited with code: 1
npm ERR! Please make sure you are using a supported platform and node version. If you
npm ERR! would like to compile fibers on this machine please make sure you have setup your
npm ERR! build environment--
npm ERR! Windows + OS X instructions here: https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp
npm ERR! Ubuntu users please run: `sudo apt-get install g++ build-essential`
npm ERR! RHEL users please run: `yum install gcc-c++` and `yum groupinstall 'Development Tools'`
npm ERR! Alpine users please run: `sudo apk add python make g++`
npm ERR! 'nodejs' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
npm ERR! operable program or batch file.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\ismai\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2023-07-07T10_59_22_861Z-debug-0.log
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you have no python installed on your OS. Install python and try again.
https://www.python.org/downloads/

If you have already installed it, you should set `python` env variable.

Comment: Python is already installed. The environment variable is also set, I can access the compiler when I write python via CMD.